# SQLAlchemy Mixin Expected Mapped Entity got Implementation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a joined-inheritance set of models.

```
class Asset(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'assets'

    asset_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    asset_type_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('asset_types.asset_type_id'))
    ...

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': asset_type_id
    }



class Vehicle(Asset):
    __tablename__ = 'vehicles'

    asset_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('assets.asset_id'), primary_key=True)
    ...
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':2
    }
```

I would like to mixin the `Vehicle` into a class with self referencing methods.  Like so:

```
from library.models import Vehicle as EsdbVehicle

class Vehicle(EsdbVehicle):

def update_usage(self, db_session, odometer):
        self.odometer = odometer
        db_session.commit()
```

When I query the `EsdbVehicle` model `vehicles = db_session.query(EsdbVehicle).all()` I get 115 results, which matches my DB.  However when I query the implementing Vehicle I get 0 results.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be 100% sure about this without setting up a DB connection and running your code but my instinct tells me that this is not working as expected because it looks to SQLAlchemy like you're trying to do table inheritance (but since you're not and the class definition is incomplete SQLAlchemy is confused) when what you really want is a mixin.

I would try something more like this:

```
class Vehicle(Asset):
    # stuff...
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': 'vehicle_subtype',
        'polymorphic_identity': 'base_vehicle'
    }

class UsageMixin(object):

    def update_usage(self, *args):
        # stuff...
        pass


class VehiclesThatUpdate(Vehicle, UsageMixin):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'updating_vehicles'
    }
```

The reason that *should* work is because everytime you extend an ORM mapped class, you are essentially telling SQLAlchemy you want to perform some kind of table inheritance. In this case, you can get away with just adding a type (for STI) because you aren't adding attributes (columns) you're just adding functionality.

If this does not work out (or is incomplete) just add a comment and I'll adjust.

EDIT: Another thought. The other thing you could do is skip the inheritance all together and just write functions that operate on the `Vehicle` class. They do not need to be methods necessarily. I often do this to avoid extra coupling between my actual SQL model and the class / method structure.

The more you use ORM's the more you start to realize that often times using *less* of their features is better.

Comment: It does appear that I cannot mixin a table, only columns, based on the docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html 

Sadly I'm trying to refactor some bad choices away and was hoping to be clever and use the mixin.  Looks like I may have to do this another way.  I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes that's correct, column and functional mixins are the only thing that will work within the bounds of SQLAlchemy's understanding of inheritance mapping. Glad to be helpful. If you are refactoring ORM code, often it can be cleaner to write an entirely new model and then just migrate the data and use interfaces to patch the new model in quickly before refactoring callers. Reason being that with ORM code you are essentially refactor two things at once, the schema AND the object model.